# Worpdress images not found slow loading time

Tags: wordpress

I am in wordpress, and many images are not found from uploads directory during loading, so the site takes 25s to display and very slow.

Is there any way, code or snipets to skip those images during loading ?

Thank you.

Comment: how the images included in the posts/pages ?

Comment: hi, i don't know, it's a client from themeforest :(

Answer (score 0):

The caching plugins fix those problems. You can use the free version of W3 Total Cache.
If you do not want to install a caching plugin, just resize your images ;)